# Execute package task asking password if I saved the package with "Encrypt All with password"

Tags: ssis

I Have a Package which will execute 7 packages using execute package task. Those 7 packages are saved with protection level as "Encrypt all data with password".

While configuring Execute Package task I selected the Location as "File System". Daily I need to run this package manually. But the Problem is I need to give password for all the 7 packages every time I want to execute it. Usually I run this package during lunch time.

Is there anyway I can store the package password programmatically? If I ran it yesterday and I didn't close the BIDS and I'm running it again today this will not ask for the password.

I also tried to build the package after the first run where it didn't ask for the password. Then I run it again without closing the BIDS. But this is still not working.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the password protection method? there are other methods where you do not need to use a password (server encryption and user encryption)

Comment: Yes, we (developers) don't have permission to deploy the packages and schedule it. So we will create a package with same protection level and the same password. So that there won't be any confusion while deploying. Also there are some other people who using the same server. So the password is required.

Comment: OK, just one more thing, if you use SQL Server connections and windows authentication throughout your package then you can use the `Do Not Save Sensitive` encryption level without any problems. If you use a database that doesn't support windows authentication then you can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you store the `package passwords` SSIS will always prompt you for entering the password when you are using `BIDS` to execute it . This is because BIDS try to open the individual `child package designer` and hence prompts you for entering the password .

So the only way is to execute it without the `dialogue prompt` for `password` is to use `sql agent` or `dtexec utility`

1.In order to execute the child packages i suggest you to create a config file for the parent package and select the property `Package Password` for all your `Execute Package Task`

[image]

2.Now in the config file enter the password for all the individual `execute package task`

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package\Execute Package Task.Properties[PackagePassword]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Password</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

3.Execute your package using `dtexec utility`

```
dtexec.exe /f "PackageLocation/Parent.dtsx"
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I will consider this.